# How To Do Query on Each Element Returned From ActiveRecord Search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets say I have a `User` model in Rails which contains `has_many :cohorts'`.  Then my `Cohort` model contains `has_many :enrollments`.  When I run:

`u.cohorts`

returned is

```
[#<Cohort id: 1, start_date: "2013-01-15", end_date: "2013-05-15", created_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", updated_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", course_id: 1, user_id: 2>,
 #<Cohort id: 2, start_date: "2014-01-15", end_date: "2014-05-15", created_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", updated_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", course_id: 1, user_id: 2>,
 #<Cohort id: 3, start_date: "2013-01-15", end_date: "2013-05-15", created_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", updated_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", course_id: 2, user_id: 2>,
 #<Cohort id: 4, start_date: "2014-01-15", end_date: "2014-05-15", created_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", updated_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", course_id: 2, user_id: 2>,
 #<Cohort id: 5, start_date: "2013-01-15", end_date: "2013-05-15", created_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", updated_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", course_id: 3, user_id: 2>,
 #<Cohort id: 6, start_date: "2014-01-15", end_date: "2014-05-15", created_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", updated_at: "2014-01-11 01:31:29", course_id: 3, user_id: 2>]
```

How would I then go about getting a list of all enrollments from that list of Cohorts?  I tried doing `u.cohorts.enrollments` with no success.  I do not want to use a `has_many through` relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with `has_many :enrollments, :through => :cohorts`? Thats a very natural way to do this.  Otherwise, You'll probably have to do something like this:

```
enrollments = u.cohorts.map(&:enrollments).flatten
```

If you look at the SQL behind these, the has_many :through is better.

Since you already have a has_many :enrollments, you can define another relationship with something like this:

```
has_many :cohorts_enrollments, :through => :cohorts, :source => :enrollments
```

Check out the options on has_many here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Comment: I have two types of Users (using cancan) - students and faculty. So I already have a `has_many enrollments` in my user model to support students having many enrollments.  I now want to lookup enrollments that are in each cohort so faculty members can see all student enrollments.  Since I already have a `has_many enrollments`, I didn't think I can also have a `has_many :enrollments, :through => :cohorts`.  I would like to do that, but didn't think it was possible.  Is it possible? That method is definitely preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `has_many ... through` to `User` model.

```
#User.rb
has_many :enrollments, through: :cohorts

# in your code
u.enrollments
```